# Initial topology for semi-norms and a fundamental system of neighborhoods

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

I read the following in some notes on Functional Analysis:
($E$ is a vector space)

[image]
Now, I believe that the message is not very clear. How this makes sense to me is as follows:

The fundamental system of neighborhoods that the author is talking about is the system of neighborhoods

$$
\mathcal{B} = \{ U_{i_1,\epsilon}\cap\ldots\cap U_{i_n,\epsilon}: \epsilon >0 \ \wedge\ \{ i_1,\ldots,i_n \} \text{is a (finite) subset of } I \}
$$

This seems like a fundamental system of neighborhoods. But maybe I am considering too many neighborhoods (in the sense that maybe the fundamental system that the author was talking about is smaller). Am I?

Comment: You don't mention that $E$ is a vector space, and thus your topic is topological vector spaces rather than general topological spaces, but I suspect this is the intended context.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, it is: I will add that detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be super picky and avoid any misunderstandings I would remove (countable) 
 and replace it with (finite). Other than that, you are right. You have a family of seminorms. At each point $x\in X$ for each seminorm $p_i$ you can consider a ball $B_i(x,\varepsilon)$ of center $x$ and radius $\varepsilon$. To generate a local base at $x$ you take all finite intersections  $B_{i_1}(x,\varepsilon)\cap\ldots\cap B_{i_n}(x,\varepsilon)$ for every $\varepsilon>0$ and for every finite family $i_1<\ldots<i_n$ in $I$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$.   If you want you could also consider $B_{i_1}(x,\varepsilon_1)\cap\ldots\cap B_{i_n}(x,\varepsilon_n)$.

Comment: Since the Question seems to center on the "notes" shown as an image, I think correcting countable to finite is an excellent point.  After all we probably don't want the singleton set containing the origin to be open.